# Changing plot's domain deforms the rendering of the y axis values

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm creating a plot in `D3.js` that changes how the y axis domain is calculated according to the type of analysis. For example :

```
 if (this.analysisType === 'REGRESSION'  ) {
      this.chartProps.y.domain(
        d3.extent(this.plotData, (d: any) => {
        return d.yb ;
      }));
    }
 if (this.analysisType === 'CLASSIFICATION' || this.analysisType === 'SURVIVAL') {
    this.chartProps.y.domain([0, 1]);
 }
```

I'm rendering one line and one area using the following functions:

```
// Define the main line function
const valueline = d3.line<any>()
.x( (d) => {
  return vm.chartProps.x(d.x);
})
.y( (d) => {
  return vm.chartProps.y(d.y);
});

// Define the area for the confidence intervals function
const confidenceArea = d3.area<any>()
.x( (d) => {
  return vm.chartProps.x(d.x);
})
.y0( (d) => {
  return vm.chartProps.y(d.yt);
})
.y1( (d) => {
  return vm.chartProps.y(d.yb);
});
```

The thing now is that while on classification and survival the plots are rendered as expected, in the regression case the y values for some reason are exceeded above the y axis.

^ This is is a classification one
[image: Here is the normal one]

and here ^ is a regression one
[image]

I'm wondering why the second plot's y-values exceed the y-axis.